# What are all the "DiskCacheIndex*.tmp" files on my phone?

Tags: temp-files

I have about a dozen files named `DiskCacheIndexnnnnnn.tmp` in my `/mnt/sdcard`, where `nnnnnnn` is some number.  All of these are emtpy:

[image]

What are they for?

Who created them?

Is it safe to remove them?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I woukd assume it's safe to delete all but the latest.  Perhaps the are similar to the ._trashes etc. files MacOS creates.

Answer (score 2):

Its the cache files for the sd card itself, its safe to delete.It is produced by apps which store data into sd card.You could tell the apps not to store it on SD if you like, if the app supports it.

Answer (score 1):

They might be from an app called "3D Gallery". There's also apparently an app for deleting them: "Junk Killer". (I haven't looked at the Market myself.)

Everything I was able to find says that it's okay to delete them. At worst, they'll be recreated as needed.